# SBT run fails when I'm launching it

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a little problem when I'm running the command `sbt run` :

```
$ sbt run 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.defaultApplication(Lcom/typesafe/config/ConfigParseOptions;)Lcom/typesafe/config/Config;
    at play.api.Configuration$$anonfun$3.apply(Configuration.scala:75)
    at play.api.Configuration$$anonfun$3.apply(Configuration.scala:71)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at play.api.Configuration$.load(Configuration.scala:71)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:203)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:61)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDev(DevServerStart.scala:60)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDevHttpMode(DevServerStart.scala:50)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart.mainDevHttpMode(DevServerStart.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at play.runsupport.Reloader$.startDevMode(Reloader.scala:207)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.devModeServer$lzycompute$1(PlayRun.scala:73)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.play$sbt$run$PlayRun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$devModeServer$1(PlayRun.scala:73)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:99)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:52)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
```

Most of errors that I met with sbt have one issue when I google it but for this kind of error, no idea how to fix that.

My file `build.sbt`:

```
import play.routes.compiler.InjectedRoutesGenerator
import play.sbt.PlayScala


version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  ws,
  filters,
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.0.0",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.7.play24",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.10.12",
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.4.0-1",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.5",
  "org.webjars" % "angularjs" % "1.4.7",
  "org.webjars" % "angular-ui-bootstrap" % "0.14.3",
  "org.webjars" % "angular-ui-router" % "0.2.15"
)

resolvers += "Sonatype Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

Anybody see one issue for this problem ?

Update with `application.conf` :

```
# This is the main configuration file for the application.
# ~~~~~

# Secret key
# ~~~~~
# The secret key is used to secure cryptographics functions.
#
# This must be changed for production, but we recommend not changing it in this file.
#
# See http://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ApplicationSecret for more details.
play.crypto.secret = "changeme"

# The application languages
# ~~~~~
play.i18n.langs = [ "en" ]

# Router
# ~~~~~
# Define the Router object to use for this application.
# This router will be looked up first when the application is starting up,
# so make sure this is the entry point.
# Furthermore, it's assumed your route file is named properly.
# So for an application router like `my.application.Router`,
# you may need to define a router file `conf/my.application.routes`.
# Default to Routes in the root package (and conf/routes)
# play.http.router = my.application.Routes

# Database configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
# db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
# db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
# db.default.username=sa
# db.default.password=""

# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
# play.evolutions.enabled=false

# You can disable evolutions for a specific datasource if necessary
# play.evolutions.db.default.enabled=false

play.modules.enabled += "play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule"
```

`project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.0")
```

Comment: something is wrong with your `com.typesafe%config` version, would definitely check https://github.com/typesafehub/config notes; in the meantime, could you show us your `application.conf`?

Comment: I update the post with the `application.conf`.

Comment: What version of Play are you running? (i.e. show us your `plugins.sbt` file)

Comment: I update with the play version.

Answer (score 1):

Update `"com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.0.0",` to `1.3.0`

According to github, missed method appears in `1.3.0` version of `ConfigFactory`

https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/config/src/main/java/com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory.java

```
 * @since 1.3.0
 *
 * @param options the options
 * @return the default application configuration
 */
public static Config defaultApplication(ConfigParseOptions options) {
    return parseApplicationConfig(ensureClassLoader(options, "defaultApplication"));
}
```

Comment: You did not update properly. Check update to my comment

Answer (score 1):

For the people meeting this problem, The way to solve it was to put the `config-1.3.0.jar` into the `lib` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The same error can happen if you put some play libraries into a provided environment classpath (as with an assembled fat jar). For example, [Flink 1.3.2](https://flink.apache.org) has an older `com.typesafe.config` library, not compatible with `Play 2.5` or further.

The way to solve is this is by shading the libraries as explained in [sbt-assembly.](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading)